# Set content type for apple-app-site-association file on nginx configuration

Tags: ios, nginx, ios-universal-links, apple-appclips

I am setting up the app clip functionality in my iOS app for which I have created an apple app site association file and placed it in the /.well-known/ directory.

I am setting the content-type as application/json as follows:

```
server {
   ...
   location /.well-known/apple-app-site-association {
      default_type application/json;
   }
}
```

I have also tried to set the content-type forcefully as follows:

```
server {
       ...
       location /.well-known/apple-app-site-association {
          types { } default_type "application/json; charset=utf-8";
       }
    }
```

However, when I curl it using command line, I get the content-type as text/html.

I am using the following curl command:

curl -v https://your_domain.com/apple-app-site-association

Please guide me with what is the correct way to set content-type for apple-app-site-association file on the nginx configuration.

Thanks!

Comment: Apologies for the wrong submission. I have modified the code above in my question.

Comment: I am setting the content-type as application/json as follows:
server {
   ...
   location /.well-known/apple-app-site-association {
      default_type application/json;
   }
}

I have also tried to set the content-type forcefully as follows:
server {
       ...
       location /.well-known/apple-app-site-association {
          types { } default_type "application/json; charset=utf-8";
       }
    }

Comment: You mean: `curl -v https://your_domain.com/.well-known/apple-app-site-association`?

Comment: Yes, I have tried both these commands.
1. curl -v https://your_domain.com/apple-app-site-association
2. curl -v https://your_domain.com/.well-known/apple-app-site-association .

For both of them, it returns text/html.

Comment: You will need to look at the entire `server` block to understand why that `location` is not being selected to process the request.

Comment: I looked into the server block. The changes are being reflected in the browser. But, when I run the curl command, it doesn't update and shows text/html. Any idea ?

Answer (score 1):

This is the bit that I added to my `server` block for the AASA file:

```
location ~ "^/apple-app-site-association$" {
    default_type application/json;
}
```